# Питон канвас с сеткой с закрашиванием клеток

Tags: python, canvas

Всем привет, мне нужно реализовать на питоне, такую штуку: ты рисуешь на холсте, нажимаешь кнопку и холст переводится в клеточную сетку где показано все клетки, которые хотяб как то были задеты, просто я пишу нейронку и хз как это реализовать, помогите пж

Comment: Хм.. Я уже видел такой вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, который отрисует поле 8 на 8 с прозрачными квадратами.

```
GRID_SIZE = 8
SQUARE_SIZE = 50
for i in range(GRID_SIZE):
    for j in range(GRID_SIZE):
        c.create_rectangle(i * SQUARE_SIZE, j * SQUARE_SIZE,
                           i * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE,
                           j * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE)
```

Но также можно отрисовывать это линиями. Так даже правильнее будет. Здесь 400 - это границы канваса:

```
for j in range(GRID_SIZE):
    c.create_line(j*SQUARE_SIZE,0,j*SQUARE_SIZE,400)
for j in range(GRID_SIZE):
    c.create_line(0,j*SQUARE_SIZE, 400,j*SQUARE_SIZE)
```